# How to efficiently lock a code block in order to avoid optimistic lock exception

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, optimistic-locking

I am not very experienced with Multithreading in Java. What I want is to set a lock for a code block. In my case i want to avoid optimistic lock exceptions, while doing some synchronization for a certain user. The method `replicateUser` can be called by multiple threads for the same user. But it is not guaranteed, that `authenticatedUser` is always the same identical object.

So how can I effeciently lock this section? What I don't want is, that the section is locked for all threads, but only for those with the same user. Can I put a lock on string objects as shown on the example below using `getUserName()`?

```java
private void replicateUser(AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser) {
    //
    // How to synchronize the following block correctly?
    //
    synchronized (authenticatedUser.getUserName()) {
        User dbUser = userRepository.findOne(authenticatedUser.getUserName());
        if (!checkIsUserReplicated(authenticatedUser, dbUser)) {
            doReplication(dbUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to provide the detail about Optimistic Lock Exception, the block synchnized is not solution for this issue.

Comment: @Vash if it was the solution, i would not have posted this question! my question in other words could be: what is the solution to avoid multiple threads writing the same record in db. since if they do, it might result in an optimistic lock exception... I updated the commend above the `synchronized` block to make it more clear

Comment: Did you figure out the way for this. I also have the same condition. i want that one of my method in service should be only locked when there is already a thread executing for same user id. If different user id comes up then it should not be locked .

Answer (score 1):

You better put lock on `authenticatedUser.getUserName ().intern ()` because it is guaranteed that once two strings are identical by contents, `intern ()` will return the same object for them.

Also, if it is guaranteed in your system, that there is only one instance of `AuthenticatedUser` class with particular user name, then you can lock directly on `authenticatedUser`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, synchronizing on authenticatedUser.getUserName() will not work because you may have multiple instances of authenticatedUser.  Two threads reading in the same authenticatedUser data will get different instances if read from different EntityManager context.  To get around this, you can either account for the occasional optimistic lock exception by wrapping your doReplication method with a try/catch block that then checks that the change was made by another thread (using em.refresh), or you can switch to using pessimistic locking as described here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Locking#Pessemistic_Locking
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PessimisticLocking

Once you've locked the authenticatedUser, you can check if it was replicated and release the lock or perform the replication.